# How to extend FOSUser Bundle in multiple bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Can somebody help me to overwrite `FOSUSerBundle` in multiple places (Bundles).

I have overwritten in separate bundle named `"UserBundle"` with `user_type=ADMIN` but now I need to inherit the same `FOSUserBundle` in `"ClientBundle"` with `user_type=CLIENT`,

Like this I have multiple roles for user one is for backend and other is for frontend and can be more. How I can achieve this?

Please help me out on the above issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't... The Symfony2 bundle architecture for inheritance is same as PHP, you can't inherit more than once a bundle as same as you can't inherit multiple class in PHP. Sorry but you need to rethink how you will split your application in multiple bundles.